# FFmpeg.AutoGen decoding h264 MP4 to an image

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I've been experimenting with the FFmpeg.AutoGen (https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen) wrapper. I have successfully made it possible to decode an MPG file to a bitmap from a .NET stream. But decoding a MP4 (h264) file gives me a negative return value for FFmpegInvoke.avcodec_decode_video2.

I've tried setting flags (such as pCodecContext->flags2 |= FFmpegInvoke.CODEC_FLAG2_CHUNKS;) but I do not get a successfull image from the stream. So what I'm looking for is a working example of decoding h264 to an image using FFmpeg.AutoGen. I know somebody has got this working (see [How to get a byte** from managed byte[] buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058044/how-to-get-a-byte-from-managed-byte-buffer)) so it is possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to decode video successfully using demo application from project and mp4 file provided by Ernstjan, the reason why it was broken - codec context which was initialized with all defaults just by using coded information, apparently that is not enough.

Fortunately the `codecContext` variable still contains coded context which was initially discovered by `av_find_stream_info`, thus we can reuse it and it works fine for me.

Thus quick and dirty solution will be replace this line:

```
AVCodecContext* pCodecContext = FFmpegInvoke.avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
```

With:

```
AVCodecContext* pCodecContext = &codecContext;
```

I'll update demo application to show few different approaches how to obtain proper codec context.

Comment: I guess FfmpegInvoke does not exist any more.